# memoir class justify problem

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, memoir

Hello I am writing the thesis using memoir class template and I would like to avoid the text to be vertically justify. For exemple when I have a figure that does not fit on page 1 it goes on page 2 but after the text on page 1 is split to be on top and bottom of the page 1 with a big blank in the middle. I would like to have the blank at the bottom only.

How could I solve this problem

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}

Comment: This looks like some sort of "underflow", if you include `lipsum` and simply generate more dummy text, does the problem go away?

Comment: If you are using [H] (float package), that is how it is supposed to operate. Don't use [H].  You can try \raggedbottom, assuming memoir is compatible.  You can also throw in \vfill where desired.

Comment: That is not the default behaviour. Please provide a short MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that sows your problem and that we can compile.